# How to solve "No such file or directory"? [LPTHW Chapter 17 example]

Tags: python

I'm currently learning LPTHW by Zed Shaw but I found a problem.

I'm trying to write by myself the whole code (without the line number, of course)

```py
    from sys import argv
    from os.path import exists

    script, from_file, to_file = argv

    print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

    # we could do these two on one line too, how?
    in_file = open(from_file)
    indata = in_file.read()

    print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

    print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
    print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL- C to abort."
    raw_input()
    out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
    out_file.write(indata)

    print "Alright, all done."

    out_file.close()
    in_file.close()
```

but the code didn't work. I kept looking for a mistake but I didn't seem to find any, so out of frustration I deleted the code I wrote and rewrote the new one, but this time I copied the code entirely from the e-book to make sure that I'm not making any mistakes. It didn't turn out okay. cmd showed this instead

```
    D:\Coding>python ex17.py test.txt new_file.txt
    Copying from test.txt to new_file.txt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "ex17.py", line 9, in <module>
        in_file = open(from_file)
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

I really have no idea where the problem is since copying the code directly from the e-book didn't help either. As an addition, I got this message when I tried to insert cat command.

```
    D:\Coding>cat test.txt
    'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Why is this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the file `test.txt` exist in `C:\Coding`? The error suggests not. The `cat` tool is a Linux/Unix tool, but you're on Windows. So use `type` or `more` instead.

Comment: as @MarkRotteveel commented, error is suggesting that the file is not present in your directory where `.py` file is. you can use `open(from_file, 'r')` to open file in read mode.

Comment: Consider getting a better book.

Answer (score 0):

```
D:\Coding>python ex17.py test.txt new_file.txt
Copying from test.txt to new_file.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex17.py", line 9, in <module>
    in_file = open(from_file)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.txt'
```

The last of the traceback tells you that the file `text.txt` does not exist.
And when your program tries to read it, it crashes.

```
D:\Coding>cat test.txt
'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

As mentioned in the comments Vikas Gautam, windows does not understand `cat` as it is a linux command.

Moving forward, here are three things you could do:

- become aware of the equivalent windows commands and substitute them while following the examples.
- use bash on windows https://www.howtogeek.com/249966/how-to-install-and-use-the-linux-bash-shell-on-windows-10/
- move to linux.
- follow a tutorial written keeping windows in mind.